# Why is my normal map ruining the look of the texture?

Tags: normal-map

I am trying to bake this model to a normal map but it's having issues.
The last image is the base mesh that's the low poly version. The higher poly version has extra details besides being subdivided, such as what's pictured in image 3. image 2 is the resulting normal map when the high-poly mesh bakes onto the low. The final/first image is the result. Why does it look like this, do I have to make the higher poly model smoother or is something  else causing this?
Here's a link to the .blend file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HWHANNt-5NxZOmWsx1HvI4hEqDY6S4aB/view?usp=drive_link

[image][image][image]
[image: Base mesh]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, added a link to the post to my file on google drive.

Comment: Thanks but your link asks for an authoization

Comment: Sorry about that. I figured it out, the cage needed activating and a buffer setting.